# best and optimal way of storing data in DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have a situation where I have to store some flags and data in DB. The contents are like

is_read `--->` to check whether user has read case study , flag 0 or 1

is_submitted `--->` to check whether user has submitted the case study flag 0 or 1

url_file `--->` url of the file uploaded by user , data type varchar(100)

Each case study can be accessed by many users.

So which among the two is optimal and best way of doing it?

1) storing every thing in one table , no duplication here 
 `id | user-id | case_id | is_submitted | is_read | file_url`

2) breaking down to table for each constraint as they are not related to each other

`id | user-id | case_id`
`<fk>`

`id | is_submitted`
`id | is_read` 
 `id | file_url`

i need all data so in 2 case it will have more joins.

And also the columns are not related to each other.

Comment: Your data types is not described very clearly. Make an effort to identify your data types, and if that will not help you then edit your question so that we can help.

Comment: @ZoharPeled updated with data types

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear my self, I guess. I should have written your data entities

Comment: @ZoharPeled is_submitted and is_read are int which will hold 0 are 1 and file_url  is varchar which stores url's like  domain.com/file/my_file.pdf

Comment: That's not what I mean. I'll try to explain: You have an entity called User. it has an Id (User_Id) and probably some other data such as first and last name that are irrelevant for this question. you also have an entity called case study. it has an id as well (case_id) and whatever other properties.
My guess is that the properties of is_submitted, is_read and file_url does not belong to a single user or a single case study, but they belong to the connection between them, and in that case, your option 1 is better. is my guess correct?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yop thnaks for the suggestion ::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

To me, it would seem that a case study is submitted by a single user.  If so, the `CastStudies` table should have a column called `SubmittedBy`.

Similarly, I would imagine that a case study has a single URL.  If so, it should have a column called `FileURL`.  If there are multiple URLs, then you would want another table, `CasestudyFiles` to store them.

As for the read flag, this seems like a many-to-many relationship between case studies and users.  As such, you would want a junction table, with columns like:

- CasestudyId
- Userid
- ReadDate

However, I am imagining all these things, because your question doesn't really explain the entities and the relationships among them.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, I would envision a table like this:

```
create table UserCasestudies (
    UserCasestudiesId int not null auto_increment primary key,
    CastStudiesId int not null references Casestudies(CaseStudiesId),
    UserId int not null references Users(UserId),
    ReadDatetime datetime,
    SubmittedDatetime datetime,
    UploadDatetime datetime,
    URL varchar(100)
) ;
```

You can add flags if you like, but I think looking at date/time of the actions is potentially more useful.

Comment: thanks for answering ,There will be 'n' users who read the case study, submit and upload their file. Each user has to submit so it will be something like all the three constraints are specific to user not to case study

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you want to optimize.

Read-performance?
Write-performance?
Reflection of human thinking models?

But you would have to test/benchmark those for both models to find what best suits your needs.

Also, you claim that those flags "are not related to each other", which is technically incorrect since they all refer to the same case study.
I would therefore advise you to go with version 1, as it is a simpler model and there's no need to complicate it.
But really, that is an opinion already.

Comment: i meant the are not internally related to each other as a whole they represent the instance of case study.